# Calling PHP from document.ready

Tags: php, javascript, document-ready

Is there a way in document ready to call php scripts?

I want to do something like this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($) {

    <?php require("readenglish.php"); ?>
    <?php require("readfrench.php"); ?>
    <?php require("readspanish.php"); ?>
    <?php 

    $opload = $_GET['opload'];
    if ($opload == "reade") {

    }
    else if ($opload == "readf") {

       echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";

       echo "document.f1.r1[0].checked = false;\n";
       echo "document.f1.r1[1].checked = true;\n";
       echo "SelectRead();\n";

       echo "</script>";

    }

    ?>

    });

</script>
```

The three php scripts create divs and add information to them from an external domain php script.

Comment: you have to know that you can't use javascript and php like that. PHP is always interpreted first(ran on server-side), while the javascript is interpreted by the browser.

Comment: PHP is *server-side* and JavaScript is *client-side*.  PHP generates a page which your browser renders.  You can use AJAX to have JavaScript talk to a PHP page to get the script.

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing client and server side with no interface there. You're going to have to use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to pull in the content from the php scripts and update your DOM accordingly.

Of course... you could also design your site in a way that makes sense. This method looks suspicious at best and almost positively has a much better, exclusively server side solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in your page:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#result').load('test.php', function() {
    alert('Load was performed.');
  });
});
```

Where, on the server, `test.php` contains your code:

```
<?php require("readenglish.php"); ?>
<?php require("readfrench.php"); ?>
<?php require("readspanish.php"); ?>
<?php 

$opload = $_GET['opload'];
if ($opload == "reade") {

}
else if ($opload == "readf") {

   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";

   echo "document.f1.r1[0].checked = false;\n";
   echo "document.f1.r1[1].checked = true;\n";
   echo "SelectRead();\n";

   echo "</script>";

}
```

This then needs to be added back into the DOM on the client side. Not good design though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery. They have a load method that does exactly what you're asking: http://api.jquery.com/load/